# Trying to dynamically set the menu

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I have the following function in my Main.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // menu.clear();

    Log.i("onPREPARAPRE Folder Size",String.valueOf(folders.size()));

    int x = 0;
    while(x < folders.size()) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,folders.get(x++));
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

`folders` is a `List<String>`.  The `Log.i` correctly displays the size of the `folders` variable at start of the app, but then the function is never called again:

1. Why aren't my menu items getting added?
2. I thought this function was called every time I open my navigation drawer?

Comment: Do you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when you want to update menu?

Comment: @RoShanShan where would I put that?  Even if I put this code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` nothing gets added in.

Comment: If you want it to be updated every time you open the navigation drawer, then put a listener in the navigation drawer opening methods

Comment: @Chud37, do you want to add item to drawer menu programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` has nothing to do with navigation drawer.  
It is an event that is triggered for the Options Menu (the one that unfolds when you tap on the 3 dots).  
If you want to add the menu items to the navigation drawer, do it like this:

```
NavigationView myNavView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.my_nav_view);
Menu menu = myNavView.getMenu();
int x = 0;
while(x < folders.size()) {
    menu.add(folders.get(x++));
}
```